# How the root database works for custom themes in wordpress

Tags: mysql, database, wordpress

Just want to know that how the default database having multiple tables of comments metacomments posts etc gonna work for another theme which might not have the same panels ? Do I have to create a new table for the required field ?

Answer (score 0):

Themes is not related to comments, Actually theme name and its settings saved in `wp-options` table. If you run the query:

```
SELECT * FROM  `wp_options` WHERE  `option_name` =  'template'
```

then you will get the activated template name of your theme.

Comment: I think you didnt get my question. I was saying that what if a new theme doesnt have all the options such as comments/replies . It may have a registration form , so now where the data will be stored of the registration form? Do we need to create a new table with the required field ?

Comment: @RaviOjha, You are talking about a specific theme. If you want theme specific functionality then yes, you have to create your own tables and store and fetch from them.